# How can I tell if a vector is normal (orthogonal) to the plane?

Tags: plane-geometry

I have to write equation of plane given 2 points $A=(-5,4,2)$ and $B(-3,2,-1)$ and vector  $u=(1,2,-3)$.
What I did was  get a vector from points $A$ and $B$ , $AB=(2,-2,-3)$ and then I found cross product between $AB$ and $u$, $n= AB \times u = (12,3,6)$  so my first question is: 
can I divide the new vector $n$ by 3 and get $n=(4,1,2)$ and is this vector normal to the plane? If yes how can I tell that it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are given the two points $A$ and $B$ and the vector $\vec{u}$. You want to find an equation of the plane that contains $A$ and $B$ and is parallel to the vector $\vec{u}$. Is that correct?

If so, then you are doing the right thing. The vector $\vec{AB}$ will be parallel to the plane and indeed the cross product $\vec{n} = \vec{AB}\times\vec{u}$ will be a normal vector for the plan. For *any* non-zero scalar $c$, the vector $c\vec{n}$ will also be a normal vector.

It looks like your calculations are correct.

And equation for the plane is
$$
4(x+5) + 1(y-4) + 2(z - 2) = 0.
$$

Comment: actually it says just write the equation of plane determined by points A and B and vector "u" it doesn't say that it  is parallel to vector "u" but also it doesn't say that vector u is orthogonal on the plane

Comment: @EndritShabani: Yeah, in that case I would guess they mean "parallel" to the plane.

Comment: okay thank you for the answer